# ng-model binded to the field doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using `ng-model` I wanted to bind fields with the array object `this.enhancements[item.id] = { checked: false, qty: 0 };` so whenever the `checkbox` is checked or `input` field has some values it will automatically get filled into the array object.

The following is the code I am currently working with. Please advise what am I doing wrong.

*home.ts*

```
export class HomePage {

  extras: any;
  enhancements: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
    this.http.get('https://www.example.com/api/enhance/11/?format=json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(response => {
        this.extras = response.Extras;
        this.enhancements = {};
        this.extras.forEach(item => {
          this.enhancements[item.id] = { checked: false, qty: 0 };
        })
    });
  }

  onChange(){
    console.log( this.enhancements );
  }

}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of extras" id="booking-enhancements-wrap-{{ item.id }}">
            <ion-col width-10>
                <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="onChange()" ng-model="enhancements[item.id].checked" ng-checked="enhancements[item.id].checked"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-70>{{ item.name }}</ion-col>
            <ion-col width-20><input type="number " id="qty-{{ item.id }} " style="width: 100%; " (input)="onChange()" ng-model="enhancements[item.id].qty" /></ion-col>
        </ion-row>=
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ionic2 Then you can't use ng-model

You have to use [(ngModel)]

see https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/

Answer (score 1):

try this
replace

```
this.enhancements = {};
```

to

```
this.enhancements = [];
```